# How can I sort LinkedHashMap<Integer, HtmlTagValues> where HtmlTagValues is a class with various values?

Tags: java, sorting

I am relatively new to Java, and trying to sort `LinkedHashMap<Integer, HtmlTagValues> newHtmlTagValues` where `HtmlTagValues` is a public class which has numerous values from a HTML page. I want to sort on the Top values.

```
public class HtmlTagValues {
    public String Top;
    public String Height;
    public String Width;
    public String Left;
    ....
}
```

The values are stored in the following way.

```
HtmlTagValues v = new HtmlTagValues();
v.Top = topValue;
v.Left = leftValue; 
hHtmlTagValues.put(nPage + ElementID, v);
```

Comment: Edited how values are stored/put in the HashMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume there is a constructor in HtmlTagValues class for all the properties

```
public HtmlTagValues(String top, String height, String width, String left) {
    this.top = top;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.left = left;
}
```

**Note:** I also presume that you have getters/setters for each property.

---

Now let's say we have the following map

```
Map<Integer, HtmlTagValues> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

map.put(1, new HtmlTagValues("Z", "10", "768", "100"));
map.put(2, new HtmlTagValues("A", "10", "768", "100"));
map.put(3, new HtmlTagValues("B", "10", "768", "100"));
map.put(4, new HtmlTagValues("D", "10", "768", "100"));
map.put(5, new HtmlTagValues("C", "10", "768", "100"));
```

Here is how we can sort our map by value, by the property 'Top'

```
Map<Integer, HtmlTagValues> sortedMap = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparing(HtmlTagValues::getTop)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Your sorted map will look like this

```
2,HtmlTagValues("A", "10", "768", "100")
3,HtmlTagValues("B", "10", "768", "100")
5,HtmlTagValues("C", "10", "768", "100")
4,HtmlTagValues("D", "10", "768", "100")
1,HtmlTagValues("Z", "10", "768", "100")
```

Fully working example:

https://gist.github.com/mackatozis/8aa81597bc33d885635cb3a9935e5cd5